# Google Firebase and Unity (C#): Unable to download png from bucket

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, download

### Specs

```
Unity editor version:       2018.2.8f1
Firebase Unity SDK version: 5.5.0
Additional SDKs:            SimpleFirebaseUnity
Developing on:              Mac
Export Platform:            Android
```

### Issue

I'm having troubles setting up a system to download pictures from storage. I'm not an expert in databases, but I wanted to give it try, just to learn how it is done.
I found Firebase very useful to store metadata on the real-time database and easy to approach even for an entry level programmer like me.

The problem is that I'm trying to download a `.png` file from a folder in storage, but I can't manage to find if the file is actually downloaded or if it's just lost in the process. I don't get any errors in the console, but when I open the folder in which the files should be, it's empty.

### Code

```
private SimpleFirebaseUnity.Firebase firebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseQueue firebaseQueue;
private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
private StorageReference m_storage_ref;

// Setup refernece to database and storage
void SetupReferences()
{
    // Get a reference to the database service, using SimpleFirebase plugin
    firebaseDatabase = SimpleFirebaseUnity.Firebase.CreateNew(FIREBASE_LINK, FIREBASE_SECRET);

    // Get a reference to the storage service, using the default Firebase App
    firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;

    // Create a storage reference from our storage service
    m_storage_ref = firebaseStorage.GetReferenceFromUrl(STORAGE_LINK);

    // Create a queue, using SimpleFirebase
    firebaseQueue = new FirebaseQueue(true, 3, 1f);
}

// ...

IEnumerator DownloadImage(string address, string fileName)
{
    var local_path = Application.persistentDataPath + THUMBNAILS_PATH;
    var content_ref = m_storage_ref.Child(THUMBNAILS_PATH + fileName + ".png");

    content_ref.GetFileAsync(local_path).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log("File downloaded.");
        }
    });

    yield return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reason for why this is not working for you including:

- security rules are not setup properly
- paths to files are not correct
- you are testing it on wrong platform (Firebase is not working well in the editor)
- your device is blocking the connection
- etc...

In order to get error messages you need to log them:

```
IEnumerator DownloadImage(string address, string fileName)
{
    var local_path = Application.persistentDataPath + THUMBNAILS_PATH;
    var content_ref = m_storage_ref.Child(THUMBNAILS_PATH + fileName + ".png");

    content_ref.GetFileAsync(local_path).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log("File downloaded.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
        }
    });

    yield return null;
}
```

Keep in mind testing it in the editor may not work.